# How to instruct Spyder3 to use a specific version of Python

Tags: python, pip

I have both Python 3.5 and 3.6 installed on an Ubuntu Machine. Spyder3 uses 3.5 but pip3 uses 3.6 by default. Spyder gives an error message upon launch that a dependency is not met. So I have to either tell Spyder3 to use Python 3.6 or tell pip3 to use 3.5 but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to change any of those, you can install a package for a specific version of python by calling pip through python as a module like this:

```
python3.5 -m pip install tkinter
```

Replace `python3.5` with the target version and `tkinter` with the target module that is required.

Hope this helps!